# how can I edit/remove info in MySQL database via bootstrap table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating an admin panel for small ecommerce website (to practice) and I have no idea how to  make php  understand which id product I want to update after I click this little `<i></i>` element because I already use `$_POST['<i> element name']` in order to detect whether or not it's ready to be updated, I know you cannot assign 2 names to one element otherwise I could use `$id = $results['id'];` as second name... any advices? I'm completely new in php. sorry if this post is stupid I just need some help...
[image]

```
$query="select * FROM productadd";
$result= mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$results = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(!empty($results['id'])) {
    while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $id = $results['id'];
        $name = $results['name'];
        $text = $results['text'];
        $price = $results['price'];
        $image = $results['image'];
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$id.'</td>
            <td>'.$name.'</td>
            <td>'.$text.'</td>
            <td>$'.$price.'</td>
            <td>
                <img src="'.$image.'" style="style="display:block;" width="100%" height="100%" ">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="add" value="asd" title="Add" name="edit" data-toggle="tooltip">
                    <i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i>
                </a>
                <a class="edit" name="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip">
                    <i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i>
                </a>
                <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip">
                    <i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, why take data out of a perfectly good array and put it in a scalar variable only to output it?

Comment: How do you intend to send this delete instruction back to the server? A `<form>`  or an AJAX call?

Comment: because I want to display it inside table rows?

Comment: `<td>'.$id.'</td>` is the same as `<td>'. $results['id'] .'</td>`

Comment: If I understand what you are saying you need to update or remove the database table fields from clicking on edit button on the table?

Comment: If I understand what you intend to do what you need is to store the values in data attributes and get it in  your javascript code, use ajax to send it as response to your php executor script to add, delete or update the current field on the table. You need someone like $(".datapoint").each(function(){}) jquery to access individual table data with same selector class